Order of functions in compiled executable
I read a book on reverse engineering, which claims that with C/C++, functions from the same source typically end up in the compiled binary next to each other, in the order they were written.
Is it really typically the case? (assuming any options to manually control it were disabled, but keeping "defaults")
What is the chance that a compiler/linker, or optimizations, would affect this? I'm not asking about any particular compiler, more like popular ones, let it be GCC and MSVC for example, and Windows / Linux as platforms.
Edit: not a duplicate of Why would gcc change the order of functions in a binary?  , my question is a "general rule" kind, not specifically about GCC.

It is more or less guaranteed that any of the higher levels of optimisation will inline code that is used just once or short enough to do so without impacting executable size too much. I'd say it was approximately true that binary code is in about the same order as the source code for most executables but that is all. They can sometimes be very different under aggressive optimisation settings. Some smarter linkers will also remove any code from component modules that is unused by the final program.

Linkers typically operate at the section level when arranging code and data in the binary. By default:

Sections are placed alphabetically in the final binary unless explicitly ordered (e.g., via linker scripts or linker options).
Sorting is applied per section, meaning functions or data within a single section aren't sorted individually unless each function or variable is placed in its own section.

When you force the compiler to generate separate sections for every function or data, their placement in the binary can be influenced by:

Alphabetical Ordering (default behaviour).
Custom Ordering (using linker scripts or options).
Priority-based Sorting (where available).

GCC + LD (GNU binutils) can place functions is data in separate sections:

-ffunction-sections: Places each function in its own .text.<function_name> section.
-fdata-sections: Places each global or static data variable in its own .data.<variable_name> or .bss.<variable_name> section.

You can eliminate dead code on function level (as it has its own section) by passing  --gc-sections to the linker
Functions and data can be sorted in the executable by leveraging the -ffunction-sections and -fdata-sections options in conjunction with a custom linker script or linker options.
Example:
ld --sort-section=name -o sorted_binary main.o

You can sort section (and functions as they are placed in separate sections) by:

Wildcard Patterns:

Use * or ? to match section names.
For example, *(.text.*) matches all sections starting with .text.


Explicit Section Order:

Specify the order of sections in the SECTIONS block.
Sections are output in the order they are listed.


Automatic Sorting:

Use the SORT() or SORT_BY_NAME() directives to sort sections alphabetically.
Use SORT_BY_ALIGNMENT() to sort sections by their alignment requirements.
use ld --sort-section command line option



MSVC is less flexible compared to GCC/Clang when it comes to automatically placing each function or variable in separate sections. However, similar behaviour can be achieved by manually assigning functions and variables to specific sections using #pragma directives or __declspec(allocate). This process can be streamlined using macros, effectively automating the assignment while achieving the same result.

functions from the same source typically end up in the compiled binary
next to each other, in the order they were written.

It would be best if you did not assume this.

"It would be best if you did not assume this." -- the OP explicitly asks "what typically happens by default?". I think you should add a TL;DR.

You might also add a note about compile time and link time optimisation where functions not specifically flagged as static or inline can get inlined at link time, hence disappear from the code as separate objects.
